# not getting response when checkbox checked React

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a response from the checkbox whenever it is checked from the following code. But none of these alerts are working when I check or uncheck boxes.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        alert('s');
        if (this.checked) {
            alert('sfaf');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. I don't see how this code relates to React, but generally `onChange` handlers would receive an `onChange` event object that you can access the checked value of.

Comment: Console.log this